# why this pointer gets garbage collected before being freed in rust

Tags: pointers, rust, memory-management, garbage-collection, unsafe

```rust
fn test() -> *const Vec<u8> {
    let b = vec![9_u8];
    let ret: *const Vec<u8> = &b;
    println!("ret ptr={:#p} inside {:#p}", ret, b.as_ptr());
    std::mem::forget(b);
    ret
}

fn main() {
    let a = test();
    let v = unsafe {
        &*a
    };
    println!("ret ptr={:#p} inside {:#p} value={}", v, v.as_ptr(), v[0]);
    println!("ret ptr={:#p} inside {:#p} value={}", v, v.as_ptr(), v[0]);
}
```

im my machine this gives:

```
ret ptr=0x00007fffc5d85690 inside 0x00005650a61cfaa0
ret ptr=0x00007fffc5d85690 inside 0x00005650a61cfaa0 value=9
ret ptr=0x00007fffc5d85690 inside 0x00005650a572a348 value=76
```

the problem in the last line where the value changes suddenly, is this some kind of bug ?

Comment: If you run the program through `cargo miri` (e.g. on the playground), miri will immediately point out hat `&*a` is dereferencing a freed pointer, so its undefined behavior, so the program has to sensible output at all.

Answer (score 8):

By using `std::mem::forget`, you've avoided *dropping* the `Vec` such that the `9_u8` will persist. However, your reference is is pointing to `b` which is a local variable and thus its memory will still be reclaimed for other function calls (as evidenced by the `println!`s). So the value you get from `v[0]` afterwards is nonsense.

By the way, the safe way to do what you've essentially done is to use [`Vec::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.leak).

Comment: To add to this, nothing is garbage collected because Rust doesn’t gave a GC but instead uses manual memory management.